# Is it possible to run type after action in ArgumentParser?

Tags: python, argparse

Generally, my goal is to validate the argument after it has been sanitized. Maybe my pipeline is wrong, but as I see it, `ArgumentParser` doesn't allow this to be done in a snap. To sanitize the argument I'm using a custom `action` and for validation, I'm using a custom `type`.

In the example below, I have the following args: `2 days ago`. I want it to be validated as a single argument. So I've made a custom action, which joins `[2, 'days', 'ago']` in one string. I'd love to validate it after with `test_type` function.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Action

parser = ArgumentParser()


def test_type(value):
    print (value)
    return value


class ActionJoinString(Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, ' '.join(values))


parser.add_argument('timerange', nargs='+', action=ActionJoinString, type=test_type)

options = parser.parse_args('2 days ago'.split())

print(options)
```

The output is the following:

```
$ python asd.py 
2
days
ago
Namespace(timerange='2 days ago')
```

So as you see, even though `timerange` was concatenated in a single string, the type-validation was performed on the array of values. Is there any easy way to make it done my way? I thought it would be great to have special `nargs` to concatenate arguments in a string, but as I see it doesn't exist.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: What you're attempting to do is pretty strange.  Why not just passing as a single argument?  `python myscript.py '2 days ago'`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `nargs` the parser allocates a list of strings to this Action.  You'll see in the `get_values` method that for '+' the strings are passed one at a time to `get_value` where they pass through `type` ( and may be tested against `choices`).  Only after this are they passed to the Action `_call__` as `values`.

So `type` is only for one string in `sys.argv`.

But your action call can do anything with the `values`. You can also use an ordinary store, and process the values after parsing.  You don't get extra points for doing everything in the parser.